# How can i unlock Gtk button event

Tags: python-2.7, pygtk, gtk3

When i click on some button, the entire application stay locked waiting a result from the method, to return something..

So, i have one Gtk.Button, and i connected him to a function, for example on_button_clicked:

```
button = Gtk.Button()
button.connect('clicked', on_button_clicked)
```

the function on_button_clicked look like this:

```
def on_button_clicked(widget):
    func1()
    func2()
    func3()
```

When the functions (func1, func2, func3) is runing, the entire application stops, waiting a result from the main function (on_button_clicked). The os say **'The Application is not responding'**.

Basicaly, the func1 encode one url, request that url using urllib, that request  return a response that is a json file, then the func2 load that json, then make a dict with informations from json, and make an iteration in this dict printing the informations.

```
func1(term):
        url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?'

        values = OrderedDict([
            ('url',url),
            ('method','flickr.photos.search'),
            ('api_key', '47a28953049fe88b32522c8997e712bb'),
            ('text', term.replace(' ', '+')),
            ('format', 'json'),
            ('nojsoncallback',1)
            ])

        url_encoded = urllib.urlencode(values)
        url_encoded = urllib.unquote(url_encoded)


        request = Request(url_encoded[4:])
        try:
            response = urlopen(request, timeout =1)
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            print 'There was an error: %r' %e
```

In this time i can't click or edit no other widget.

Comment: The question is really hard to understand. Can you edit it and maybe include a code sample?

Comment: Don't you think we should know what func1 2 and 3 are doing?

Comment: basicaly, the functions encode one url, request that url using urllib, that request is a json file, then the function2 load that json, then make a dict with informations from json, and make an iteration in this dict..

Comment: Copy the contents please. Looks like the request is timing out

Comment: added the content of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func1()`, `func2()` and `func3()` are blocking the gtk main loop. In this case, it is probably the network request. Therefore, you have to use threads.

Probably something like this:

```
from threading import Thread
...
def on_button_clicked(widget):
    Thread(target=func1).start()
```

However, you should note that you have to use `glib.idle_add()`, if you want to modify gtk widgets from a thread. To hide a widget from a Thread for example, you would do `glib.idle_add(widget.set_visible, False)`.